# How to Apply the same effect in multiples fields with an eye button?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

Hello guys i' am trying to apply an effect of eye button i

I managed to do one as follows

```
const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false)

<RecoveryGroup>
            <ButtonRecovery>
              <RiLockPasswordLine size={22} />
            </ButtonRecovery>
            <RecoveryInput value={password} type={show ? 'text' : 'password'} placeholder='Digite sua senha aqui' onChange={({ target }) => setPassword(target.value)} />
            <ButtonEye onClick={() => setShow(!show)} type='button'>
              {show ? <FaEye size={18} /> : <FaEyeSlash size={18} />}
            </ButtonEye>
          </RecoveryGroup>
```

but I'm trying to do the same for another field, creating a new const, and passing them like this, but it just doesn't work.

```
const [show2, setShow2] = useState(false)
  const [password2, setPassword2] = useState('')

<RecoveryGroup>
            <ButtonRecovery>
              <RiLockPasswordLine size={22} />
            </ButtonRecovery>
            <RecoveryInput value={password2} type={password2 ? 'text' : 'senha'} placeholder='Digite sua senha aqui' onChange={({ target }) => setPassword2(target.value)} />
            <ButtonEye onClick={() => setShow2(!show2)} type='button'>
              {show2 ? <FaEye size={18} /> : <FaEyeSlash size={18} />}
            </ButtonEye>
          </RecoveryGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there are some typos in this line:

```
<RecoveryInput value={password2} type={**password2** ? 'text' : '**senha**'} placeholder='Digite sua senha aqui' onChange={({ target }) => setPassword2(target.value)} />
```

It should be:

```
<RecoveryInput value={password2} type={show2 ? 'text': 'password'} placeholder='Digite sua senha aqui' onChange={({ target }) => setPassword2(target.value)} />
```